# Wcf Web API filter by DateTimeOffset

Tags: odata, wcf-web-api

I am currently using WCF Web API Preview 5 and am trying to filter a list of users where the LastModifiedDate is greater than or equal to the provided datetimeoffset:

```
 http://api.myapp.com/users?$filter=LastModifiedDate ge datetimeoffset'2011-06-01T14:03:00+00:00Z'
```

However all I am getting is an error saying:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Query.ParseException: '.' or '(' expected (at index 34)
```

The filtering seems to be working fine as this filter returns the requested user

```
http://api.myapp.com/users?$filter=UserId eq 1

-- XML Response
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfUser xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <User>
    <ExtensionData />
    <CreateDate />
    <CreatedById>1</CreatedById>
    <IsDeleted>false</IsDeleted>
    <LastModifiedById>1</LastModifiedById>
    <LastModifiedDate />
    <Name>Joe</Name>
    <UserId>1</UserId>
  </User>
</ArrayOfUser>

-- JSON Response
[
  {
    "CreateDate":
    {
      "DateTime":"\/Date(1306481778297)\/",
      "OffsetMinutes":0
    },
    "CreatedById":1,
    "IsDeleted":false,
    "LastModifiedById":1,
    "LastModifiedDate":
    {
      "DateTime":"\/Date(1306936979717)\/",
      "OffsetMinutes":0
    },
    "Name":"Joe",
    "UserId":1
  }
]
```

Just cannot get it working with the DateTimeOffset filter so am I creating the filter incorrectly? Or is there something else at play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
http://api.myapp.com/users?$filter=LastModifiedDate ge datetimeoffset('2011-06-01T14:03:00+00:00Z')
```

or

```
http://api.myapp.com/users?$filter=LastModifiedDate ge (datetimeoffset'2011-06-01T14:03:00+00:00Z')
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I did try both of those thinking the first one would provide me with an oData function but I still got an error saying 'String' cannot be converted to type 'DateTimeOffset'. I therefore presumed that this function did not work or was not available. I then tried your second example and the one I provided in my question. However both of those queries provide the error message in my question. I upgraded the framework yesterday to Preview 6 when Glenn released it but this hasn't changed anything which leads me to think its something with the filter query.

Comment: I think it could make sense to file a bug [here](http://wcf.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic)

Comment: Ok done, will update question when when I receive a response. Accepted as answer as bug report needed to be filed.