# WCF Web API DateTimeOffset Problems

Tags: wcf, wcf-web-api

I am using WCF Web API Preview 6 with its inbuilt Test Client to request a resource by Id. The object returns with all its data except for the ‘CreateDate’ and ‘LastModifiedDate’ properties which are of type `DateTimeOffset` and are empty. I have tried setting the values manually by calling `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` and `DateTimeOffset.Now` and although the values are set on the object they never make it through to the other end in the response.

I have also tested this by changing my property types to `DateTime` and manually setting their values by using `DateTime.Now` and everything works fine and I get what looks like a DateTimeOffset value.

```
<CreateDate>2011-12-13T16:15:47.4269538+00:00</CreateDate>
<LastModifiedDate>2011-12-13T16:15:47.4269538+00:00</LastModifiedDate>
```

Does anybody know if there is a problem with the use of the `DateTimeOffset` type in Preview 6 or is it something I am doing wrong? I have had a similar problem with filtering the fields using oData (see [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313633/wcf-web-api-filter-by-datetimeoffset))

I have also submitted [this](http://wcf.codeplex.com/workitem/121) bug report to the WCF Web API codeplex site on the filtering issue. However that was over two weeks ago and haven’t had any response.

After many hours of testing and debugging I am running out of options on this one! So if anybody out there can provide me with some helpful hints it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a Web API issue, it's Microsoft serialization issue.  The XmlSerializer does not handle DateTimeOffset.  I believe it has the same issue with TimeSpan.

Just implement IXMLSerializable on your object and handle it yourself.

See here [How can I XML Serialize a DateTimeOffset Property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377036/how-can-i-xml-serialize-a-datetimeoffset-property)